# Swipe through views with curl animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, gesture-recognition

I need to switch views by swiping with a curl animation for transition. 
I tried PageControl (and other approaches -.-), but it's not what I need for several reasons, so I'll go for the GestureRecogntion, but I stuck.

My problem by now is the architecture. There is the firstVC, calling the SecondVC, onto which I add the subviews (of a third VC) to, which should be swipeable. I don't know if it's possible at all to swipe through subviews from another VC or if it's the code or the IB setup that won't do the job (It's my first time with gesture recogntion)

So by now I just loaded 4 dummy subviews when the secondVC loads. My GR-Code (just for the leftswipe, but rightswipe is more or less the same..)

```
- (void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

NSInteger viewToBeShown = 0;
NSString *nextSubviewStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"view%d", (viewToBeShown)];

if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft){
    if (currentSubview >0) { 
        viewToBeShown = currentSubview-1; 
        nextSubviewStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"view%d", (viewToBeShown)];
        Ubg *nextSubview = [[Ubg alloc] initWithNibName:nextSubviewStr bundle:nil];
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubview:nextSubview.view];
```

Could you tell me if that could should basically work (and it's just my IB setup that's not correct)? This is driving me nuts! If you need any other information, just let me know.

Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: nextSubview.view will never be shown, because its superview (self.view) is removed from the view hierarchy in the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code used for curl animation

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1];

//setting animation for the current view
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.navigationController.view cache:YES];

//Next ViewController to push
nextPage *detailViewController = [[nextPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"nextPage" bundle:nil];

//Push the next viewcontroller to NavigationController
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:NO];
[detailViewController release];

//Start the Animation
[UIView commitAnimations];
```